# Inverse Fourier transform of $\Gamma(z)\zeta(2z)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, gamma-function, riemann-zeta

I wish to calculate the following series:

$$f(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{2\pi itn}\Gamma(a+ibn)\zeta(2(a+ibn))$$
I hope to somehow use the Poisson summation formula, since I already know that -
$$\Gamma(a+2i\pi b)\zeta(a+2i\pi b) = \mathcal{F}[\frac{e^{-a u}}{e^{e^{-u}}-1}](b)$$

The problem is that I have a factor of $2$ inside the Riemann zeta function, so the expression above doesn't fit exactly to my series. If anyone has an idea on how find the inverse Fourier transform of $\Gamma(z)\zeta(2z)$ using what I already know (maybe using some identities of the gamma/zeta function), or if you have another idea on how to evaluate the series, I'd be happy to hear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is the following formula: $$
\Gamma (z)\zeta (2z) = \frac{{\pi ^z }}{{2z(2z - 1)}} + \pi ^z \int_1^{ + \infty } {\left( {t^z  + t^{ - z + 1/2} } \right)\left( {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {e^{ - n^2 \pi t} } } \right)\frac{{dt}}{t}} .
$$ I do not know whether it helps in this case.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which vertical line (*). For $o > 1$ we have $$\Gamma(o+it) \zeta(2(o+it)) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i t u}  e^{-o u}f(u)du, \qquad f(u)= \sum_{n\ge 1} e^{-n^2 e^{- u}}$$

For $o \in (0,1)$ replace $f(u)$ by $f(u)-1/u$, for $o\in (-K-1,K)$ replace it by $f(u)-\sum_{k=-K}^1 c_k u^{-k}$ where $c_k = \lim_{s\to k} (s-k) \Gamma(s)\zeta(2s)$.

> (*) Try first with $1/s$, for $\Re(s)>0$ it is the Laplace transform of $1_{u > 0}$, for $\Re(s) < 0$ it is the Laplace transform of $-1_{u < 0}$.

Comment: Could you explain where the formula for the first equation comes from? I'm not familiar with this identity.
And do you think there's a way to express this series more concretely? I'm not sure if this way will make the series easier to understand

Comment: $n^{-2s}\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}e^{- x}dx=\int_0^\infty y^{s-1}e^{-n^2 y}dy =\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-su} e^{-n^2 e^{-u}}du$